# Comparing Xml by values of nodes or attributes in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-validation, xmldiff

I want to compare two (or more) XMLs files by values of nodes or attributes. I am not interested by node names or attributes.

Searching on google i found XMLDiff Patch ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx ), but it not work for me.. or i don`t know how to make settings to work for me.

FileA

```
  <Root odata.context="http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(i53ojihzxawmvtyyvztbaelk))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata">
  <value>
    <name>Photos</name>
    <kind>EntitySet</kind>
    <url>Photos</url>
  </value>
  <value>
    <name>People</name>
    <kind>EntitySet</kind>
    <url>People</url>
  </value>
  <value>
    <name>Airlines</name>
    <kind>EntitySet</kind>
    <url>Airlines</url>
  </value>
  <value>
    <name>Airports</name>
    <kind>EntitySet</kind>
    <url>Airports</url>
  </value>
  <value>
    <name>Me</name>
    <kind>Singleton</kind>
    <url>Me</url>
  </value>
  <value>
    <name>GetNearestAirport</name>
    <kind>FunctionImport</kind>
    <url>GetNearestAirport</url>
  </value>
</Root>
```

File B

```
<Root odata.context="http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(i53ojihzxawmvtyyvztbaelk))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata">
  <value>
    <name>Photos</name>
    <kind>EntitySet</kind>
    <url>Photos</url>
  </value>
  <value>
    <name>People</name>
    <kind>EntitySet</kind>
    <url>People</url>
  </value>
  <value>
    <name>Airlines</name>
    <kind>EntitySet</kind>
    <url>Airlines</url>
  </value>
  <value>
    <name>Airports</name>
    <kind>EntitySet</kind>
    <url>Airports</url>
  </value>
  <value>
    <name>Me</name>
    <kind>Singleton</kind>
    <url>Me</url>
  </value>
  <value>
    <name>GetNearestAirport</name>
    <kind>FunctionImport</kind>
    <url>GetNearestAirport</url>
  </value>
</Root>
```

I want to validate values of each nodes or attributes.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you compare two XML Documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167946/how-would-you-compare-two-xml-documents)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750879/comparing-xml-by-nodes-names-and-attributes-names-in-c-sharp

Comment: I don't want to validate structure. Is it possible to validate values of each nodes.@Balaji

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it your self and the structure of the xml documents is known and constant you could maybe do something like this (supposing that xdocB is the valid document):

```
class NodeComparer : IEqualityComparer<XmlNode>
{
  public bool Equals(XmlNode x, XmlNode y)
  {
    if (x == null || y == null)
      return false;

    if (x.ChildNodes.Count != y.ChildNodes.Count)
      return false;

    var nodeNames = new [] { "name", "kind", "url" };

    for (int i = 0; i < x.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
    {
      foreach (var nodeName in nodeNames)
      {
        if (!x[nodeName].InnerText.Equals(y[nodeName].InnerText))
          return false;
      }
    }

    // TODO some testing of attributes

    return true;
  }

  public int GetHashCode(XmlNode obj)
  {
    return 1;
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  XmlDocument xdocA = new XmlDocument();
  xdocA.Load(pathA);
  XmlDocument xdocB = new XmlDocument();
  xdocB.Load(pathB);

  var nodesA = xdocA.SelectNodes("Root/value").Cast<XmlNode>();
  var nodesB = xdocB.SelectNodes("Root/value").Cast<XmlNode>();

  var comp = new NodeComparer();
  var errors = nodesA.Where(na => !nodesB.Contains(na, comp));

  if (errors.Count() > 0)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("ERRORS: ");
    foreach (var error in errors)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", error.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(xn => $"{xn.Name}: {xn.InnerText}")));
      Console.WriteLine();
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("No Errors");
  }

  Console.ReadLine();
}


}
```